# The inner-most exception in c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Is there a way to get the inner-most exception without using :

```
while (e.InnerException != null) e = e.InnerException;
```

I'm looking for something like `e.MostInnerException`.

Comment: You could make `MostInnerException()` an extension method that *hides* that loop. There is not built-in shortcut to get there.

Comment: I'm curious... how often do you come across (and what) exceptions that have multiple layers of useful information?

Comment: @Sayse if an exception occurs in a low level function it can be propogated and caught/rethrown with extra semantic information. While it's not often that you get extra information it does happen. I.e, I could throw an exception from my `NetworkConection` - `new BufferOverflowException()` which will then be caught by my `NetworkService` and rethrown - `new NetworkConnectionException(networkConnection, exception)`.

Comment: @DanPantry - Ah right, I wasn't accounting for rethrowing

Comment: Or `TargetInvocationException` usually has an inner exception too.

Comment: Why do you want the innermost exception?  I would only ever use this in a catch.  I certainly hope this isn't for logging purposes, any decent logging tool throws the whole chain in, just logging the innermost exception wouldn't guarantee you the necessary information to identify the issue

Comment: Be careful, if you face an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx), actual inner most exceptions won't be retrieved with this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend on Hans Kesting's comment, an extension method might come in handy:

```
public static Exception GetInnerMostException(this Exception e)
{
    if (e == null)
         return null;

    while (e.InnerException != null)
        e = e.InnerException;

    return e;
}
```

Comment: @Sayse yes it can. You need reference of type `Exception`, the reference can still be null

Comment: @Rik this method is invoked such that `e` is the `Exception` object it is being invoked on, if `e` is null you will get a `NullReferenceException` before it hits the call - unless you invoked it like a static method `Exception.GetMostInnerException(exception)`

Comment: This would still be legal: `Exception ex = null; ex.GetMostInnerException();' which leads to a NullReferenceException in the extension method. Try it.

Comment: You need 

if (e == null)
    return null;

Comment: This could be turned into a recursive function which IMO makes more sense than the reference re-assignment - `if(e.InnerException != null) return e.InnerException.GetInnerMostException(); return e;`

Comment: @DanPantry I prefer loops to recursion personally, all that pushing and popping on the stack, what's the point?

Comment: @Mick: The recursive function reads easier. I was confused why OP and Patrick were using `while` because I didn't expect the re-assignment of `e` within the function. Further, TCO can eliminate this problem.

Comment: Thanks Fors yours response, i have to develop a method to get the most inner exception, that means there is no property already exists in the .Net framework.

Comment: we have to contact Microsoft to add a property MostInnerException to the Exception class :)

Comment: if you have it, that 'll be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer that differs a bit: you can create an enumerator.

With

```
public static IEnumerable<Exception> EnumerateInnerExceptions(this Exception ex)
{
    while (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        yield return ex.InnerException;
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

You can do

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("1", new Exception("2", new Exception("3", new Exception("4"))));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    foreach (var ie in ex.EnumerateInnerExceptions())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ie.Message);
    }
}
```

So, technically, you are not longer using a while loop a visible way :)

Comment: Why "yield return ex" instead of just "return ex"?

Comment: That makes more sense now.  But I think you're answering a question that allows you to use yield, not the one that was asked.

Comment: You're right. But if it could inspire whoever wants to retrieve the whole exception chain, then it's ok.

Comment: Yes I wouldn't ever use the answer given.  I'd use a logging tool that reports the entire chain.